# How can I store the value from a python socket in a double?

Tags: java, python, sockets, double

I am basically sending doubles from a Java application to a Python server. Now, how can I retrieve those doubles and store them in a variable?

This is what I do to retrieve the data / the doubles:

```
data = client_sock.recv(1024)
```

Now `data` is a string. I want to have a double. What can I do?

Comment: In what format does your Java code send the double?

Comment: well, I basically write doubles to a dataoutputstream

Comment: You should probably use `struct` modules.

Comment: sounds great. any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert from IEEE 754, you will need to use the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html), something like this:

```
value = struct.unpack("<d", data[:8])
```

Note that the `<` indicates little-endian. If that doesn't work, try `>d`.

Comment: Great! Just to let you know what worked for me: I used `>d` and since `struct.unpack()` returns a tuple i used this to get the actual value: `struct.unpack(">d", data[:8])[0]`